# Is it possible to save appSettings in database

Tags: .net, ado.net, web-config, app-config

I know straight forward how to implement with e.g. Ado.Net code first, but I couldn't find in the documentation anything about this and would ask you guys/gals.

Is it possible to save appSettings in database?

Just saying (and to avoid why-do-you-want-to-do-that comments), it is for a specific customer setup where this seems to be the best solution.

Comment: You can store whatever you want in the database, are you asking how to continue to use the existing settings objects but let them query a database instead? or ...?

Comment: I'm asking for if .Net has a class which instead of using config file, uses database for saving of appSettings part. So I do not want to use config file, but database to save appSettings.

Comment: Most modern databases supports XML data types, so you can even store the entire config file in the database if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To conclude.

No, there is no .Net library that will load/save appSettings to a database instead of the config file.

It is straight forward however to have a code first ADO.Net model with key value which can be used, instead of appSettings.